# Google Cloud Storage - renaming "directories" using the PHP API

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket that looks like:

```
bash-3.2$ gsutil ls gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/

gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/2013-second-half-cancellations.csv
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/F59PH_860_High_resolution.jpeg
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/HostBuildZoneProcess.txt
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/office.jpg
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/4 Big McCarthy Lake Road/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/6001 Johntown Creek Rd/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Listings/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Local_Utilities/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Rental_Documents/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/bobcat.png
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/testfile.png
```

I'm trying to use the StorageObject rename function. I have the following code:

```
$bucket_name = '<my bucket name>';
$object_name = 'AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog';

$bucket = $client->bucket($bucket_name );
$object = $bucket->object( $object_name );

echo "Object found, name = " . $object->name() . "\n";
```

This produces: "Object found, name = AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/";

```
echo "Object info:\n";
print_r( $object->info() )
```

Note: If I don't append the "/", the name() function works, but the info() function
Throws a "File not found" exception. Inconsistent. But when it works:

```
Array
(
  [kind] => storage#object
  [id] => <my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog//1570061029345142
  [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<my bucket name>/o/AR7020014%2Ffile_manager%2FTestBlog%2F
  [mediaLink] => https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/<my bucket name>/o/AR7020014%2Ffile_manager%2FTestBlog%2F?generation=1570061029345142&alt=media
  [name] => AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/
  [bucket] => <my bucket name>
 << stuff removed for some brevity >>
)
```

Then:

```
$new_name = 'AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1';
$new_object = $object->rename( $new_name );
print_r($new_object);
```

This produces:

```
 Array
 (
     [kind] => storage#object
     [id] => <my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1/1603307775687371
     [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<my bucket name>/o/AR7020014%2Ffile_manager%2FTestBlog-1
     [mediaLink] => https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/<my bucket name>/o/AR7020014%2Ffile_manager%2FTestBlog-1?generation=1603307775687371&alt=media
     [name] => AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1
     [bucket] => <my bucket name>
     << stuff removed for some brevity >>
 )
```

BUT... The result leaves me with

```
bash-3.2$ gsutil ls   gs://idx-acnt-gs.ihousedev.com/AR7020014/file_manager

gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/2013-second-half-cancellations.csv
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/F59PH_860_High_resolution.jpeg
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/HostBuildZoneProcess.txt
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/office.jpg
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/4 Big McCarthy Lake Road/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/6001 Johntown Creek Rd/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Listings/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Local_Utilities/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/Rental_Documents/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/bobcat.png
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/testfile.png
gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1
```

Leaving my "directory" TestBlog in place, but creating a new "file" named TestBlog-1. We
have implemented a virtual file system for our users, which is pretty well done, but for
this - renaming directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file structure you see in the GCS is only visual. As mentioned in the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork):

> To the service, the object **gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt** is just an
> object that happens to have "/" characters in its name. There is no
> "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name.

Therefore, `TestBlog` in your case is not really an object on its own.

In order to [rename](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#storage-rename-object-php) the object you will first need to copy it, giving it a new name, and then remove the original:

```
$bucket = $storage->bucket('[BUCKET-NAME]');
$object = $bucket->object('AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/test_file.txt');

$object->copy($bucket, ['name' => 'AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1/test_file.txt']);
$object->delete();
```

As you have multiple objects under `TestBlog`, you will need to iterate through them, renaming them one by one.

---

This can also be done with the `gsutil` tool:

```
gsutil mv -r \
gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog/* \
gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/AR7020014/file_manager/TestBlog-1/
```

Comment: Thank you - got most of the way there, this is good confirmation. The gsutil is not an option, we are implementing a file system within our web-based product for our clients.